# sort only single column in jqxgrid programatically

Tags: jqxgrid

I have the following code for jqxgrid and I want to set a single column ('Col1') sortable dynamically. How could i achieve this. Thanks for your solution and advice in advance.

```
$("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid({
    source: data,`enter code here`
    columns:[
        {text: 'Col1', datafield: 'Row', width:100},
        {text: 'Col2', datafield: 'Row', width:100},
        {text: 'Col3', datafield: 'Row', width:100},
        {text: 'Col4', datafield: 'Row', width:100},
    ]
});
```

Comment: You want to have only one `sorted column` at any time?

Comment: Yes, thats what i wanted

Comment: There is no `Sorting Before Event`. Sorry, I will try by using jquery when I have time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sortby function in jQX Grid to sort the field dynamically. Please see the below code.

```
$("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid('sortby', 'Col1', 'asc');
```

If you want to sort in descending order, you can change 'asc' to 'desc'.

Or you can use sortcolumn property in source object. You can change your source object as below.

```
var source =
{
datatype: "xml",
datafields: [
    { name: 'ShippedDate', type: 'date' },
    { name: 'Freight', type: 'float' },
    { name: 'ShipName' },
    { name: 'ShipAddress'},
    { name: 'ShipCity'},
    { name: 'ShipCountry' }
],
root: "entry",
record: "content",
id: 'OrderID',
url: url,
sortcolumn: 'ShipName',
sortdirection: 'asc'
};
```

Hope that helps.